# What is the difference between “ParseObject.put()” and “ParseObject.add()”?

Tags: parse-platform

I am learning about Parse database when I came across this, please explain it with example

I referred this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180097/what-is-the-difference-between-put-and-add-method-in-statehelper-in-jsf-2) but I couldn't understand the green ticked answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good if you could specify which Parse SDK you are talking about, but I will consider we are talking about the Android SDK.

`ParseObject.put()` can be used to set a value to an object's field:

```java
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

`ParseObject.add()` can be used to add a value to an object's field of type ARRAY:

```java
gameScore.add("skills", "flying");
gameScore.add("skills", "kungfu");
gameScore.saveInBackground();
```